# How to fetch data with relation in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `students` table that is related to `schools` table. The problem is, when I try to fetch all schools' data, it does not include the students that are associated in the api response.

But it more confuses me, student name was displayed in terminal when I try to loop and print. Although I have tried the below line but still won't work.

```
has_many :student, foreign_key: :school_id, primary_key: :id
```

Do you have idea why?

---

The `students` table has columns `school_id` that referenced to `schools` table.

**schools_controller.rb**

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    schools = School.includes(:student)

    schools.each do |school|
      puts school.student.collect(&:name) // student displayed in terminal
    end

    render json: { message: "sample", data: schools }, status: :ok
  end
end
```

**school.rb**

```
class School < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :student
end
```

**student.rb**

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**12345_create_students.rb**

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.references :school, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model relations is actually fine. Your problem probably is in your controller.

Use `preload` instead of `include`, and in your return statement you should include the `student`.

[learn the differences here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-use-includes-in-rails-7-643b5e1451c4)

Your code should look like these:

```
schools = School.preload(:student)

render json: schools, include: :student
```

Comment: thanks this is working! i thought that if we add `include` clause it will automatically fetch the relations. I tested if remove any of `preload` or `include` it won't fetch the relation, so basically these two are required.

Answer (score 0):

Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for

and try below code

```
school.rb

class School < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :students
end

student.rb

class Student < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :school
end
```